# Configure Hg to not ask for user name and password on command line

Tags: mercurial

When I try to clone a https-authenticated Mercurial repository (e.g. from kiln), it asks me for my user name

```
C:\temp\test>hg clone https://<my-login-name>.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Group/test
http authorization required
realm: kiln
user:
```

We want to invoke the `hg clone` command from our GUI application with any URL provided by the user and ask the user *on demand* for the user name and password, if they are required.

How can I configure Mercurial to invoke an arbitrary script which returns the user name/password, similar to scripts whose paths are defined in the environment variables `GIT_ASKPASS` or `SSH_ASKPASS` for Git?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can configure your credentials in your user-wide `hgrc` (`mercurial.ini` in the user profile directory, on Windows):

```
[auth]
foo.prefix = example.com/path
foo.username = user
foo.password = password
```

Afterwards, the requests for this server will silently use the credentials provided in the `hgrc` file.

See the [docs on `hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) for more information.

---

**Update:** After studying the TortoiseHg sources a little (the code in question being the `SyncWidget.inclicked` and `SyncWidget.pullclicked` methods in [sync.py](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src/default/tortoisehg/hgqt/sync.py)), I've found out that TortoiseHg, which does precisely what you're trying to achieve, apparently first tries the URL for the auth request, and, if it's been given, asks the user for the login and password, to rebuild a full URL (with credentials) and supply it to `hg pull`.

I guess you can do the same.

Comment: What is `foo` in your sample? The problem is that before we execute any clone command, we should request the user/password details to store them in the `mercurial.ini`. Isn't there the possibility to let Mercurial call a script on demand - similar to `GIT_ASKPASS` or `SSH_ASKPASS` for Git?

Comment: @MikeL.: `foo` "is used to group arguments into authentication entries", to quote the linked docs. Regarding your problem, I must admin I don't fully understand your actual goal. Care to update the question with a more detailed description of the workflow? What's the GUI wrapper you mentioned? What are the URLs "the user might enter"?

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
hg clone https://user:password@host:port
```

Is such solution not workable for you?

Comment: No, because the user might enter URLs similar to the one in the question.